# Reading ?= arguments to dynamically set debug mode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I was wondering how to read the arguments from a url, ie. `localhost:12345?debug=true` and be able to set the debug mode. I originally wanted to use the same controller I use by default, however I got an error when I tried to set #define DEBUG because it wasn't at the start of the file, which means I need a separate controller to do this, but how do I check to see if ?`debug=true` is there, and to check if debug is set to true rather than false?

Answer (score 1):

You are making too much work for yourself.  In your web.config, you can set the compilation to be in debug mode (or not)

```
<compilation debug="true">
```

If this is set in your web.config, use the framework to tell you if you are in debug mode or not.  If the above line (debug="true"), then the `HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled` will return true.

```
if (HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
{
    DoSomethingDebuggy();
}
else
{
    DoSomethingElseCompletely();
}
```

Now, you no longer need to append a random query string for debug mode (which I am sure will make your routes and links happier).  However...if you really really want to keep that query string, then in your controller/action, you can use the following:

```
public ActionResult Home(){
    var debugParam = Request.QueryString["debug"];
    //be sure to check for null or empty string before casting to a bool
}
```

Comment: @MichaelM - Attach your staging server to your production database for quick testing. Or make a copy of the db, then attach that to your dev environment.  Or use Elmah to log all exceptions so you can see the stack trace.  You cannot change the compiled dll back into a debug dll since it compiled differently.

Comment: Again, you should more look for ways to replicate errors in your staging site and not trick your environment into doing something its not literally built to do.  Thats my 2 cents on how you should manage a production and staging environment.  Gather the steps, the input information and replicate.

Comment: @MichaelM running production in `debug` mode is an awful idea. Part of your job should be educating the person who does have say in the matter, and offering an alternative solution... PS. You can turn off bundling WITHOUT turning on debug mode: `EnableOptimizations`

Comment: And like @Tommy said, there are compilation differences, and your debug site should be hitting a different database and potentially other functionality should be disabled, like sending emails. `debug` mode in production will have more negative implications (like security, for one) than positive ones helping you "debug" live.

Comment: Agreed. You don't want to run in debug mode in production; that's a huge security hole. If you need help getting at the errors, you can use a logger like Elmah. If you need to debug minimized JS/CSS, Chrome's dev tools can handle that with source maps (see https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging#source-maps).

Answer (score 0):

So because in my project, in the .cshtml file, I was using razor to check to see if the debugger was set, I just added an extra argument, || Request.QueryString["string"] == "value" and it solved my problem. A one line fix, where string is the name of the argument you want to look for.